# LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp__ in the .obj file in Line 1

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I'm not sure what's going wrong. I'll describe the problem, followed by my understanding of what's going on. It's a simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iViewNG-Core.h>

int main(int argc, char ** args) {

    iViewVersion version;
    iViewRC rc = iView_GetLibraryVersion(&version);

    if (RC_NO_ERROR != rc)
        printf("ERROR returned by iView_GetLibraryVersion(): %d\n", rc);

    printf("The version of the libiViewNG is: %u.%u.%u.%u\n", version.major, version.minor, version.patch, version.build);

    return 0;
}
```

The error description:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__iView_GetLibraryVersion@4 referenced in function _main SMI_TrialTests  c:\Users\Rakshit\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SMI_TrialTests\SMI_TrialTests\SMI_TrialTests.obj

I confirmed that the code is indeed reading iViewNG-Core.h because the auto-fill lets me use functions declared in the file. I did this by adding the lib and include directory correctly in the appropriate VC++ directories. Since this a linker issue, where am I going wrong?

I am new to C++ and I know there are tons of duplicated LNK2019 questions but none of them seemed to solve my problem.

Linker output:

> /OUT:"c:\users\rakshit\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SMI_TrialTests\Debug\SMI_TrialTests.exe" /MANIFEST
>   /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"c:\users\rakshit\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SMI_TrialTests\Debug\SMI_TrialTests.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE
>   "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib"
>   "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib"
>   "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL
>   /PGD:"c:\users\rakshit\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\SMI_TrialTests\Debug\SMI_TrialTests.pgd"
>   /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
>   /ManifestFile:"Debug\SMI_TrialTests.exe.intermediate.manifest"
>   /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /VERBOSE /LIBPATH:"C:\iView NG
>   SDK\lib\lib-Windows7-32" /TLBID:1

Comment: can you post the linker output, not only the error?

Comment: You might want to add a tag for the library you are trying to use, I don't know what `iViewNG-Core.h` is. Further sidenode: In C++ code you should be using `#include<cstdio>` (or better drop it) and `std::cout <<` instead of `printf`.

Comment: *Since this a linker issue, where am I going wrong?* -- Well, you don't start looking at header files, since header files have nothing to do with the linker -- header files are only used in the compile process, and your modules compiled successfully.  You need to specify to the linker where those functions you're calling are located, probably in an external library,

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did point the same to the linker in the additional library directories. I basically added the path to the SMI library provided by them.

Comment: @RakshitKothari -- Nope, you need to specify the name of the libraries, not just the directory where they're located.

Comment: @RakshitKothari But did you also add an option to actually **link** against that library? (With g++, this would be `-lname` to link against `libname.a` or `libname.so`)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Just did. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @RakshitKothari -- Look at the linker output. You would expect to see your library name there, but from looking at it, I don't see any names other than the standard ones like "odbc32.lib", "uuid.lib", etc.

Comment: @DanielJour and Paul - Well I have 36 DLL files in the lib folder. Should I individually add them in the additional library directory? I know, it might sound like you're trying to talk to a chimp but I don't know any of this :(

Comment: @RakshitKothari -- No, DLL's are only used when your program is running.  Where are the ".LIB" files?  I believe you need to get familiar with the entire build and run process.  1) Compiling , 2) Linking, and 3) Running.  Compiling only creates the object files, the linker links these object files together to get the final executable.  Once the executable exists, then running the executable requires the DLL's it is dependent on.

Comment: Yes, you right @PaulMcKenzie, could you point me to a website that can teach me the same? I am not familiar with this at all.

Comment: Turns out I don't have any .lib files. This is weird. The folks from SMI (it's an Eye Tracking company) provided an SDK with no .lib file.

Comment: @RakshitKothari - OK, now that is a separate question that hopefully there is a link to on SO.  How to build and run an application that has no .LIB file, and only a DLL.  Short answer -- `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.  Other answer -- build a LIB file from the DLL and use that (won't go into details).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I used the following code 
#pragma comment (lib, "libiViewNG-LibCore.lib")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123488/discussion-between-rakshit-kothari-and-paulmckenzie).

Answer (score 4):

Examining the symbol `__imp__iView_GetLibraryVersion@4`, it can be broken into two chunkcs:

- `__imp_`: This means `__declspec(dllimport)`.
- `_iView_GetLibraryVersion@4`: This is the actual symbol, mangled as a C (or `extern "C"`) `__stdcall` symbol, where the parameters total 4 bytes in size.

Considering this, and going by your code, the function causing the issue is likely:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) iViewRC __stdcall iView_GetLibraryVersion(iViewVersion*);
```

I would suggest checking that the LIB file for the DLL containing this function is being passed to either `cl` or `link` (in the former case, `cl` will pass it to `link` for you).

Comment: I used the following code:

#pragma comment (lib, "libiViewNG-LibCore.lib")

Comment: @RakshitKothari Is that the LIB file you need?  ...I'm not really familiar with iView, truth be told, i just spent a good deal of my free time learning how to demangle MSVC decorated symbols.